# Append string to start and end of line regex (notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having trouble formulating how to append the following to the beginning and end of the line in notepad++ :

Beginning `('`

End `,10)`

I tried using the following, but none would even match the beginning of the line:

`%s/.*/"&"`

`^`

When I used `^` this matched the beginning of line but if I tried to appending `^(` it would just replace the line with `^` .

My sample data looks like:

```
/.../.../.../.../.../
\…..\\\…..\\\…..\\\
%00../../../../../../etc/file
%00/etc/file%00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match the beginning of line, use `^` anchor. Since `(` is part of regex, it needs to be escaped:

[image: Replace Front]

Same goes for matching end-of-line: use `$` and `,10\)`:

[image: Replace Back]

Comment: Life saver, thanks! I'll accept when I can

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`^(.*)$`

to capture everything.

Then replace with `\('\1,10\)`,

where `\('` is the beginning part, `,10\)` is the end, and `\1` is what you capture.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `^.*$`, replace by `('$0,10)`.

`$0` is a back-reference referencing the full match, `^` and `$` are anchors that respectively match the start of the string and its end *in the search pattern* (they have no meaning in a replacement pattern, in which they are understood as the literal characters).